# Dart: Is it a good coding practise to exclude linter omit_local_variables_types rule on tests?

Tags: dart, linter

First of all, I have a very long experience with PHP, but I'm very new on dart and with testing.

I want to use a dart library and when I opened on VSCode, I got a lot of linter omit_local_variables_types rule warnings in the tests files.

You can check, as an example, this one: https://github.com/JobiJoba/dolphhinsr_dart/blob/master/test/computeCardsSchedule_test.dart

So, I'm wondering:
**Should I do a refactory the code and remove these type annotations? Or should I setup linter to exclude test files from this rule?**

My doubt is because in some tests like this one:

```
test('should return later for cards that are reviewing and not yet due', () {
    String id = generateId();
    Combination combination = Combination(front: [0], back: [1]);

    ReviewingCardState stateCard = ReviewingCardState(
        master: id,
        combination: combination,
        lapses: 0,
        lastReviewed: today,
        factor: 1000,
        interval: 13.3);

    String computeSchedule = computeScheduleFromCardState(stateCard, laterTmrw);

    expect(computeSchedule, equals('later'));
  });
```

Some types can be easily inferred, like `Combination` and `ReviewingCardState` but `String` isn't.

So, my question is: **I'll be easier for understanding the tests to keep this type annotations and so it's a good coding practise? Or the idea behind linter's rule omit_local_variable_types haven't exceptions? Could it be a better approach a mixed one like this one using `var` and `String` and excluding tests for this linter rule?**

```
test('should return later for cards that are reviewing and not yet due', () {
    String id = generateId();
    var combination = Combination(front: [0], back: [1]);

    var stateCard = ReviewingCardState(
        master: id,
        combination: combination,
        lapses: 0,
        lastReviewed: today,
        factor: 1000,
        interval: 13.3);

    String computeSchedule = computeScheduleFromCardState(stateCard, laterTmrw);

    expect(computeSchedule, equals('later'));
  });
```

Comment: Personally, I think it is rather clear that `computeSchedule` is a `String` since we have the `expect` method who takes `equals('later')`. Alternative, you could call the variable `scheduleString`.

Comment: The use of types for local variables does also introduce the risk of removing the generic part of types. I have unfortunately seen lot of code on Stackoverflow with something like `List list = a()` where `a()` returns `List<int>`. The problem is that `list` now has the type `List<dynamic>` which is properly not what we wanted. But Dart thinks you want to remove the generic part of `List<int>` since you have specified `List` as type. This problem would not happen if `list` was declared as `var` or `final` since Dart would here determine the type from the returned type of the method call.